# Free fast and easy animation with sound

Tags: animation, free

I'm looking for a quick way to make a video clip from a series of images, combined with sound. I have about 30 images, and just need them to be played one at a time, with a 1-2 second delay between each one, and I'll have a sound file to attach.

Any suggestions on what software I can use? I have Windows 7 and XP, or I'm willing to install any flavor of Linux if there's some specialty that would work well. I'll install whatever software I need, as long as it's free.

The clip just needs to be playable on the web - so a Flash movie might work, but I'd prefer a real video format if possible, so it can be posted to YouTube.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Re-opened: see this post on meta for explaination http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/113/questions-about-video-should-this-question-be-re-opened

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Win7, just use [Windows Movie Maker](http://explore.live.com/windows-live-movie-maker?os=other). It is a video editing program usually shipped with Windows that will do all you need.

I used it for a similar thing [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tf8DZxltEOk%27).

Comment: Wow, that's absolutely perfect for what I need. I didn't realize Windows Live came with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure this question actually belongs here since it's more of a nuts-and-bolts of video editing / exporting, but I'll give it a stab before it gets closed.

Ultimately, YouTube videos are encoded as Flash, so one way or another you're going to end up with a Flash movie. Often if you're starting with Flash you're doing it because you want additional interaction abilities (users clickability, etc.).

For something as straightforward as this, I'd probably use AfterEffects or Final Cut, but those aren't free and Final Cut isn't available for W7. I am assuming that you're not looking to invest in a full-on nonlinear editing package, so you might want to look into the free trial of Camtasia (www.techsmith.com) or some other similar product. With Camtasia I know you can import still image files and specify their duration, then import and slide your audio clips along the timeline to match them up. Once that's done you can export for whatever you want your end-result format to be and upload it to YouTube from there.

This [link](http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=132460) gives some goot pointers as to format, file size, etc. Remember: GIGO!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Turns out Live Movie Maker will work perfect for me, but I'll hang on to these names in case I need them in the future. And I wasn't really sure if this question belonged here or not, but I could find a better Stack Exchange site, so I figured I'd give it a shot. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The commercial product [Slideshow Box](http://www.slideshowbox.com) would probably do the trick for you. It creates flash files.